# How merging two sequential models to make one is different from using a single Sequential Model?

Tags: tensorflow

I am learning about autoencoders. I want to know what is the difference between combining two sequential models to make one sequential model is different from just using one sequential model. The architecture of both the models is same .But the difference is that we have to provide input shapes for two models for the first combined model.

```
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,input_shape = [3]),
                                    tf.keras.layers.Dense(3)
])


encoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(2,input_shape = [3])])
decoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([tf.keras.layers.Dense(3,input_shape = [2])])
autoencoder = tf.keras.models.Sequential([encoder,decoder])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.keras.layers.concatenate` to merge Tensorflow keras sequential model.

**Sample code**

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import concatenate
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model, Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input

sequential_model1_in = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
sequential_model1_out = Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu', name='layer_1')(sequential_model1_in)
sequential_model1 = Model(sequential_model1_in, sequential_model1_out)

sequential_model2_in = Input(shape=(28, 28, 1))
sequential_model2_out = Dense(64, input_dim=20, activation='relu', name='layer_2')(sequential_model2_in)
sequential_model2 = Model(sequential_model2_in, sequential_model2_out)


concatenated = concatenate([sequential_model1_out, sequential_model2_out])
out = Dense(1, activation='softmax', name='output_layer')(concatenated)

merged_model = Model([sequential_model1_in, sequential_model2_in], out)
```

Take a look on Tensorflow [Intro to Autoencoders](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/generative/autoencoder)